# Can you make a city all industry and just ship in workers from another city in SimCity 2013?

Tags: simcity-2013

If I set up a world that’s basically just industry, drilling, exporting, and a few other essentials can I just like up a bus terminal and rail terminal and send in workers from my densely populated city and other cities? Or will the industry fall apart due to not having enough workers?

Answer (score 2):

The industry will fall apart.

Relying on commuting workers seems like it would be a nice way to get around the small maps, but commuting is limited and buggy.

Also, you will want tech points eventually (from a university), tech points barely commute at all.